# Switch to Fragment through swipe up/down

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, fragmentstatepageradapter

I'm having some trouble with implementing a certain feature within my app. **What I would like to achieve is being able to swipe up/down to see certain fragments**.

I am currently using a ViewPager to scroll horizontally through three Fragments, using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Let's call these three fragments the "HorizontalFragments" (green in the image) - the user is able to navigate them by swiping left or right. Also, I have two "VerticalFragments" (orange in the image). What I would like the user to be able to do, is access those by swiping up or down, from any of the horizontal fragments.

[image]

I did have a look at the [Umano AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel), but that only works for sliding a panel up, not swiping down.

Is there any way this is achievable? I would love to receive your input, also if there are better ways to approach the problem than by using Fragments, for example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is interested, the [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2) class from Android X can do exactly this.

You can create a ViewPager2 with a vertical scroll orientation, with inside of it a nested ViewPager2 with a horizontal scroll orientation.